# How to deserialize avro files

Tags: java, avro, snappy

I would like to read a hdfs folder containing avro files with spark . Then I would like to deserialize the avro events contained in these files. I would like to do it without the com.databrics library (or any other that allow to do it easely).

The problem is that I have difficulties with the deserialization.

I assume that my avro file is compressed with snappy because at the begining of the file (just after the schema), I have

> avro.codecsnappy

written. Then it's followed by readable or unreadable charaters.

My first attempt to deserialize the avro event is the following :

```
public static String deserialize(String message) throws IOException {
    Schema.Parser schemaParser = new Schema.Parser();
    Schema avroSchema = schemaParser.parse(defaultFlumeAvroSchema);

    DatumReader<GenericRecord> specificDatumReader = new SpecificDatumReader<GenericRecord>(avroSchema);
    
    byte[] messageBytes = message.getBytes();
    Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(messageBytes, null);
    GenericRecord genericRecord = specificDatumReader.read(null, decoder);

    return genericRecord.toString();
}
```

This function works when I want to deserialise an avro file that doesn't have the avro.codecsbappy in it. When it's the case I have the error :

> Malformed data : length is negative : -50

So I tried another way of doing it which is :

```
    private static void deserialize2(String path) throws IOException {
    DatumReader<GenericRecord> reader = new GenericDatumReader<>();
    DataFileReader<GenericRecord> fileReader =
            new DataFileReader<>(new File(path), reader);
    System.out.println(fileReader.getSchema().toString());

    GenericRecord record = new GenericData.Record(fileReader.getSchema());

    int numEvents = 0;
    while (fileReader.hasNext()) {
        fileReader.next(record);
        ByteBuffer body = (ByteBuffer) record.get("body");
        CharsetDecoder decoder = Charsets.UTF_8.newDecoder();
        System.out.println("Positon of the index " + body.position());
        System.out.println("Size of the array : " + body.array().length);
        String bodyStr = decoder.decode(body).toString();
        System.out.println("THE BODY STRING  ---> " bodyStr);
        numEvents++;
    }
    fileReader.close();
}
```

and it returns the follwing output :

> Positon of the index 0
>
> Size of the array : 127482
>
> THE BODY STRING  --->

I can see that the array isn't empty but it just return an empty string.

How can I proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this when converting to string:

```
String bodyStr = new String(body.array());
System.out.println("THE BODY STRING  ---> " + bodyStr);
```

Source: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-byte-array-to-string-in-java/

Comment: Don't comment like "Try this", "Do this". Please explain the issue and how your solution resolving it.

Comment: it does not compile, the String constructor doesn't take a byteBuffer as a aparemeter

Comment: sadly the result is the same.

Comment: Before running, I would try to check if `body.hasArray()` isn't `false`.

Comment: I did, it was true.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that you are on a good way. However, your `ByteBuffer` might not have a proper `byte[]` array to decode, so let's try the following instead:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[body.remaining()];
buffer.get(bytes);
String result = new String(bytes, "UTF-8"); // Maybe you need to change charset
```

This should work, you have shown in your question that `ByteBuffer` contains actual data, as given in the code example you might have to change the charset.

List of charsets: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html

Also usful: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html

Comment: Too bad, the string is just empty? Or does it contain weird characters?

Comment: 0 characters, so dumb I haven't checked it before. On the other hand I think my deserialisation with the method deserialize2 is just not working because I removed the snappy compressing part and it also fails, which is unexpected.